# Separating input into virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, virtual-machine, virtual-desktop

I currently have a laptop, with both a built in pair of a keyboard and trackpad, as well as a keyboard and mouse attached via USB. I would like so somehow split my monitor into two "views," each with its own cursor, and a pair of input devices.

For example, I would like Microsoft Word in one half of my screen, and Firefox in another. If I type/move my external keyboard/mouse, the cursor in MS Word should move/type. If I do the same on my built-in pair of keyboard/mouse, the cursor in Firefox should move/type. But I want to be able to do both simultaneously, with neither side being affected by the other side.

The reason I want this is so that I can share my laptop with someone else, and we can both work at the same time. Is this even possible? The first thing I thought of is a virtual machine, but I have no clue how to attach different input devices to different virtual machines.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no practical way to do this. Windows will associate any attached keyboards and mice with the host machine. There is no way to separate them in the way you want.

I